# copy content file to multi files in Linux

Tags: bash, cat

I want to copy the content of file in Multiple files have the same extension how to do that using linux command

I try Run the commond :

```
cat  t1.txt  >  /etc/apache2/site-available/*le-ssl.conf
```

and

```
echo  "hello"   > /etc/apache2/site-available/*le-ssl.conf
```

but Give me an error result  "  Ambiguous redirect"

Any ideas?

Comment: You should mention the error and not make us guess that it is "ambiguous redirect".  Is that the error?

Comment: Could you double-check that your sentence is grammatically correct

Comment: This is the error that appears to me
  Ambiguous redirect

Comment: Can you please not ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630917/copy-content-file-to-multi-files-the-same-extenstion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy content file to multi files the same extenstion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64630917/copy-content-file-to-multi-files-the-same-extenstion)

Comment: @Dominique The content of the last post was not of the correct specifications
Generally I have removed it because it is closed  by the site
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirect will not duplicate a data stream.  If you want multiple copies, use `tee`.  For example:

```
< t1.txt tee /etc/apa.../*le-ssl.conf
```

Comment: good  
work fine  when used it 
but when i want overwrite on files  >> ??

Comment: If you want to append to the files, use `tee -a`

Comment: V.good but How to control and determine the addition of the required content
To the penultimate line for the existing villas.
To clarify:
cat  /etc/apa.../*le-ssl.conf  =  
<virtual host>
r
</virtual host>
how add overwrite before line
 </virtual host> in files

Comment: Sounds like you want `awk`

Comment: I found what I needed
Via :  sed = 
sed -i -e "/<\/VirtualHost>/r y.y" -e "s///" *-le-ssl.conf;